# don't want R to convert char to logical values by default

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a table of characters, however, R keeps converting columns containing "T" char with "TRUE".
I'm using the following code:

```
tab1 <- as.matrix(read.table("table.txt", sep=" "), stringsasfactors=F)
```

I tried adding the option: as.is=T but no use.

I don't want R to convert "T" values to logical values of TRUE.
Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: perhaps you should try and move `asIs = TRUE` inside the call to `read.table` and NOT inside the `as.matrix` call.

Comment: Thanks Henrik for point this out, I tried it just now but still didn't work; used the following code:

Comment: used this code but didn't work: tab1 <- as.matrix(read.table("cc_chr22.pre", sep=" ", as.is=T), stringsasfactors=F)

Comment: this tutorial should help you out: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/raw_data.htm

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
read.table("table.txt", sep=" ",colClasses = "character")
```

In the [`read.table`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) helpfile you'll find:

*Note: to suppress **all conversions** including those of numeric columns, set colClasses = "character".*